# Commands dont work even if i add sleep and return in ahk

Tags: autohotkey

when I‘m making a script, I can‘t make two functions happen.

All details first: I‘m using Auto Hot Key‘s current version.

code:

```
<+<!`::Sound beep 627,92   
       Sleep, 100    
       Sound beep 837,92    
       return
```

only Sound beep at pitch 627 is happening, not the other beep.
I try other‘s suggestions by copy pasting them, they work, but my handwritten script doesn‘t work.

did I do any mistake? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have more than one command executed by a hotkey, put the first line beneath the hotkey definition and make the last line a return:

```
<+<!`::
    SoundBeep 627,92   
    Sleep, 100    
    SoundBeep 837,92    
return
```

For more details, read the [Hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) page.